# CSS Grid - is that what we need "subgrid" for?

Tags: css, css-grid

I am trying to create a layout with css grid, which allows me to break out of the grid at child level.

The "main content" ( [main] ) should stay at a fixed maximum value like you use `max-width: ...rem; margin: 0 auto;`

[image: layout goal]

To break out of the grid I found this article: https://cloudfour.com/thinks/breaking-out-with-css-grid-layout/

If I now try to apply this, for example like this:

```
grid-template-columns: [full-start] minmax( 20px , 1fr ) [main-start] repeat( 6, 1fr ) [main-end] minmax( 20px , 1fr ) [full-end];
```

unfortunately the grid becomes apparently explicit (?) and it doesn't "fill" when I tell the children that they should be displayed in [main] as if the grid was implicit like if it is a simple grid: `grid-template-columns: repeat( 6 , 1fr );`

So as soon as I tell the children that they are in [main], I no longer have the usual control over them. They are no longer displayed side by side but explicitly occupy the track [main] - is that what we need "subgrid" for?

What I also expect to be able to do is to tell the "escapees": `grid-column: main-start / span 3;`

It is important that the whole thing is realized on a child basis, because I cannot work in other containers (CMS).
I also don't know the number of images, so I can't work with :nth-of-type etc. so it could also look like this:

[image]

Optically of course a certain pattern is formed in the picture, but when I want to insert after the larger rectangle, which is spread over 4 columns and two rows, let's say 30 more rectangle, then they should simply be continued until an element/picture with special instructions comes.

I haven't tried subgrid yet, because I won't be able to work productively with my user base for several years.

Can I solve simply by css grid? Is there anything I have not thought of?

thanks

Comment: creating a repeating pattern via :nth-child(12n ...  x) might be what you need ? https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/mdPaMob

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer but no, i cant deal with :nth-child because as I said I don't know how many images / elements there will be. i have added an image to the original post.